# Display Images stored on filesystem in aspx.

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I'm having a little trouble with This and i hope that someone could give me a hand. My database currently stores a machine name, URL and Filename that relates to a file kept in the file system.

The code I have work well with files stored in the same directory as the website, however needs currently require the images to be kept on a separate network server. The file path I'm using for these images are all correct to I'm thinking there must be some form of permission getting files from outside the websites root folder.

I'm currently working on IIS 7.5 express and visual web developer 2010. I cannot for the life of me find a way to assign permissions for the file to be accessed by my ASP.net website. The account I'm using has full read / write privileges to the server folder too so I can't for the life of me figure out why the file will display perfectly well if I used the path as a run command but if i try displaying it on the website it falls over. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I came across same error while access image from network system..how your path is mentioned in c# code.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET returns a *link* to a file to the browser inside an `img` tag. Browser, when encountering such a tag, will ask the server that the link points to, to serve the file. Unless the other server works as a web-server you can not get the images to display.

The easiest way technically would be to configure the other server to serve the images as a static content/move images to your web-server.

If the images absolutely must be on that machine and under no circumstances can it act as a web-server then you would need to programm an image handler to you application that would fetch the images from that machine to your server and stream them from memory to clients.

Comment: OK thank you. Sounds like a lot of effort for something simple. I'll have to convince my manager its no different storing them on the web server to a networked storage location.